# Href format using master page php

Tags: php, pagination

I saw a similar post on stackoverflow but it failed to anwser my question.

I am using pagination to display results and the link is coming up broken when I add the master links. Most likely as I am incorrectly using the correct format.

Have tried a few formats to try to get it working based on other posts

```
<a href='../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=' .$j. ' id='page_a_link'>Next</a></span>
```

or

```
../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=$j
```

but neither work.

**PHP PAGINATION SHOWING PAGE NUMBERS**

```
<?php
    if(isset($page))
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) As Total FROM products");
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows)
        {
            $rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $total = $rs["Total"];
        }
        $totalPages = ceil($total / $perpage);
        if($page <=1 )
        {
            echo "<span id='page_links' style='font-weight:bold;'>Pre</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page - 1;
            echo "<span><a id='page_a_link' href='../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=$j'>< Pre</a></span>";
        }
        for($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
        {
            if($i<>$page)
            {
                echo "<span><a href='../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=' .$i. ' id='page_a_link'>$i</a></span>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<span id='page_links' style='font-weight:bold;'>$i</span>";
            }
        }
        if($page == $totalPages )
        {
            echo "<span id='page_links' style='font-weight:bold;'>Next ></span>";
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page + 1;
            echo "<span><a href='../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php?page=' .$j. ' id='page_a_link'>Next</a></span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and marked as deprecated as of PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing double quotes with single quotes, that's why it breaks. Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($page))
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) As Total FROM products");
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows)
        {
            $rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $total = $rs["Total"];
        }
        $totalPages = ceil($total / $perpage);
        if($page <=1 )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">Pre</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page - 1;
            echo '<span><a id="page_a_link" href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=' . $j . '">< Pre</a></span>';
        }
        for($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
        {
            if($i<>$page)
            {
                echo '<span><a href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=' .$i. '" id="page_a_link">' . $i . '</a></span>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">' . $i . '</span>';
            }
        }
        if($page == $totalPages )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">Next ></span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page + 1;
            echo '<span><a href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php?page=' .$j. '" id="page_a_link">Next</a></span>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Also, the HTML code you generate isn't valid, as you assign the same ID to multiple elements. Consider changing id="page_links" and id="page_a_link" to class="page_link" and class="page_a_link" respectively, then change #page_links and #page_a_link in your CSS to .page_links and .page_a_link

Comment: Hi wojciech. Still getting a error `Warning: include(2) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Active\Formula One\admin\admin.master.php on line 83` ... Line 83 being `$totalPages = ceil($total / $perpage);` . Works without the masters so is defiantly a formatting issue

Comment: Line 83 can't be $totalPages = ceil($total / $pagepage); as the error you get is caused by the include() function somewhere in your code. Can you CTRL + F for include and paste the line that contains it here?

Comment: What is your code on line 83? The error indicates that a file you have included could not be found.  Check that the path is correct, and keep in mind that when using include in a sub item, the relative paths are relative to the main script.

Comment: the include is at the top of the page `<?php include("../script/dbconnect.php"); ?>`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to include number 2, so my guess is you probably have something like include($page); in your code. That is wrong, since include is used to include another file in your code.

Comment: is the error not cause by the master page though as when I remove the admin.master.php is works.

Comment: You need to show us your admin.master.php file, specifically line 83.

Comment: Thanks for all the help wojciech. With you and @DaGhostman I was able tot fix it. $page was indeed the issue and I just needed to change the value and it worked. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning two values to `page` in the URL `'../admin/admin.master.php?**page**=list_products.php&**page**=' .$j. '` try replacing `page = $j` with `page_num = $j` or something of your choice and replace it in the  and in the code.